# Port 80 filtered can't open it . Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu

I have install nginx-full package in ubuntu. Then make listen port 80. Try to open port 80 but still show filtered.

```
I use nmap -sS 183.63.219.79
```

then check the trouble must be from iptables:

```
   -P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-N KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-N KUBE-FIREWALL
-N KUBE-FORWARD
-N KUBE-KUBELET-CANARY
-N KUBE-NODEPORTS
-N KUBE-PROXY-CANARY
-N KUBE-SERVICES
-N MAILCOW
-N ufw-after-forward
-N ufw-after-input
-N ufw-after-logging-forward
-N ufw-after-logging-input
-N ufw-after-logging-output
-N ufw-after-output
-N ufw-before-forward
-N ufw-before-input
-N ufw-before-logging-forward
-N ufw-before-logging-input
-N ufw-before-logging-output
-N ufw-before-output
-N ufw-reject-forward
-N ufw-reject-input
-N ufw-reject-output
-N ufw-track-forward
-N ufw-track-input
-N ufw-track-output
-A INPUT -j MAILCOW
-A INPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A INPUT -m comment --comment "kubernetes health check service ports" -j KUBE-NODEPORTS
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes externally-visible service portals" -j KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j MAILCOW
-A FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -j KUBE-FORWARD
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes externally-visible service portals" -j KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-mailcow -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-mailcow -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-mailcow ! -o br-mailcow -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-mailcow -o br-mailcow -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.1.0.0/16 -m comment --comment "generated for MicroK8s pods" -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.1.0.0/16 -m comment --comment "generated for MicroK8s pods" -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A DOCKER -d 172.22.1.3/32 ! -i br-mailcow -o br-mailcow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.22.1.249/32 ! -i br-mailcow -o br-mailcow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.22.1.3/32 ! -i br-mailcow -o br-mailcow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.22.1.11/32 ! -i br-mailcow -o br-mailcow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.22.1.253/32 ! -i br-mailcow -o br-mailcow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.22.1.253/32 ! -i br-mailcow -o br-mailcow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.22.1.253/32 ! -i br-mailcow -o br-mailcow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.22.1.13/32 ! -i br-mailcow -o br-mailcow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8983 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.22.1.250/32 ! -i br-mailcow -o br-mailcow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12345 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.22.1.250/32 ! -i br-mailcow -o br-mailcow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4190 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.22.1.250/32 ! -i br-mailcow -o br-mailcow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.22.1.250/32 ! -i br-mailcow -o br-mailcow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.22.1.250/32 ! -i br-mailcow -o br-mailcow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.22.1.250/32 ! -i br-mailcow -o br-mailcow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-mailcow ! -o br-mailcow -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-mailcow -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A KUBE-FIREWALL -m comment --comment "kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets" -m mark --mark 0x8000/0x8000 -j DROP
-A KUBE-FIREWALL ! -s 127.0.0.0/8 -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m comment --comment "block incoming localnet connections" -m conntrack ! --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT -j DROP
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -m mark --mark 0x4000/0x4000 -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod source rule" -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod destination rule" -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

after have a look with

```
ss -atn sport == 80
State                   Recv-Q                  Send-Q                                   Local Address:Port                                     Peer Address:Port                  Process                  
LISTEN                  0                       511                                            0.0.0.0:80                                            0.0.0.0:*                                              
LISTEN                  0                       511                                               [::]:80                 

                          [::]:*
```

i don't find any clue about it. An help would be thankful

Answer (score 0):

This more information about the iptables

```
iptables --table filter --list --numeric
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MAILCOW    all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
KUBE-NODEPORTS  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes health check service ports */
KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW /* kubernetes externally-visible service portals */
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-before-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-reject-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-track-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MAILCOW    all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
KUBE-FORWARD  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding rules */
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW /* kubernetes externally-visible service portals */
DOCKER-USER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  10.1.0.0/16          0.0.0.0/0            /* generated for MicroK8s pods */
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.1.0.0/16          /* generated for MicroK8s pods */
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-before-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-track-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-before-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-reject-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-track-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.22.1.3           tcp dpt:8443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.22.1.249         tcp dpt:6379
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.22.1.3           tcp dpt:8080
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.22.1.11          tcp dpt:3306
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.22.1.253         tcp dpt:587
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.22.1.253         tcp dpt:465
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.22.1.253         tcp dpt:25
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.22.1.13          tcp dpt:8983
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.22.1.250         tcp dpt:12345
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.22.1.250         tcp dpt:4190
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.22.1.250         tcp dpt:995
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.22.1.250         tcp dpt:993
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.22.1.250         tcp dpt:143
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.22.1.250         tcp dpt:110

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain KUBE-FIREWALL (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets */ mark match 0x8000/0x8000
DROP       all  -- !127.0.0.0/8          127.0.0.0/8          /* block incoming localnet connections */ ! ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT

Chain KUBE-FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding rules */ mark match 0x4000/0x4000
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod source rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod destination rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain KUBE-KUBELET-CANARY (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain KUBE-NODEPORTS (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain KUBE-PROXY-CANARY (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain KUBE-SERVICES (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain MAILCOW (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Please don't use answers to provide more information, edit your question instead.

Comment: Sorry, My first time. I will modify it. Thanks

Comment: please do not post more information as an Answer to your question.